# Oracle Connection String for ODP.NET with LDAP name

Tags: .net, oracle, connection-string, odp.net, ora-12170

I'm using the current version of ODP.NET and trying to connect to an Oracle Server using an LDAP name. I tried the basic string:

> Data Source=ServerName;User Id=RemovedUserId;Password=RemovedPwd;

The connection attempt just times out with the following error:

> ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

I can connect with via TOAD with using the same LDAP, User ID and Password from the same box.

Do I need use something different than "Data Source" or do I need to add an LDAP prefix to the server name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to find the fully qualified name in my case it was in the following format: server.domain/instance

Still not sure how TOAD resolves it with just the instance name.

Comment: TOAD doesn't do just instance name, it's most likely using Oracle's TNS service, indicated by your TNS: timeout message.